# jQuery - load/replace a navigation with a new navigation randomly each time the user refreshes the home page

Tags: jquery

I’m pretty new to jQuery and am finding it very difficult finding a plugin/ script that can help me achieve what I would like to, there are scripts that randonly change a background image and lots of rotators that auto refresh, it's not quite what I'm after. I’m building a website for an artist and would like to load/replace a navigation with another navigation randomly each time the user refreshes the home page, a little unconventional I know but part of the whole art experience I guess...

I’d like to replace the ul.home-nav-left class randomly with e.g. ul.home-nav-left-1, ul.home-nav-left-2, ul.home-nav-left-3 - each one of these navs shows different artistic work and are css sprites - I have all that working great so don't need help with that bit, I don't want to randomly replace the list items but rather the whole unordered list.

Any assistance or a point in a direction would be a great help, thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen the concept so I may be wrong but I would advise against doing this.

Comment: I can see that it may cause a usability issue but there is a permanent menu too that never changes, it's just a way to show different work...is that why you'd advise against it, or is there another reason?

Comment: Ah I see, it's more of a random gallery/thumbnail type of thing. I misunderstood, I thought you were going to change the main navigation. And yes, I think that would have caused usability issues.

Comment: Yes it is a random-gallery-thumbnail-type thing, probably the best description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a random index.
And use the "home-nav-left" in your nav s, with the css ".home-nav-left { display: none; }".

But the generated random number on a short range will be often the same.

So you will need a way to remember the last menu displayed for a user (cookie, database log, session, ...).
If you have access to php, use rand() function, way easier, but with the same drawbacks.

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){  
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from); 
}   

$(document).ready(function(){  
    var r = randomFromTo(1, $('.home-nav-left').length);  

    $('.home-nav-left').eq(r - 1).show();  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4LWH/

Comment: I'd like one of the lists to display if then user has JavaScript turned off and each ul class is neccessary because each one has a different image sprite in it in the css.

Comment: I'll wrap each ul in a div with the same class, the uls will have unique classes

Comment: Add a "nojs" class to <html> tag. Remove it at the start of the jQuery ready function code. Also add a ".nojs ul.home-nav-left:first-child { display: block; }" in the css. But this solution will not work in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I wouldn't do that in jquery I would do that in a server side language (ASP/PHP/.NET). You could write out all your navigation options and then place a simple 'display:none' on all but the randomly selected navigation, or even better, only write out the randomly picked navigation option.

Comment: Thanks very much for you input. I am a simple web designer though and wouldn't know how to go about that! :)